# UIView Auto expand the height to fill bottom of supporview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, swift2

Both A and B UIView  are inside scrollView. As you can see in the image UIView B isn't filling and fit to the bottom of the 5.5 screens. Is there is any solution to automatically grow the UIView B to fit to screen bottom.
[image]

Comment: Hi. what I see is that you are trying to fit the views which are inside a scroll view. if so, then what is the purpose of the scrollView may I ask? the scrollView comes to action only if its contentSize is greater than its bounds right

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just remove the existing height constraint, add a new height to match the remain space

```
 let hightConstraint = getConstraint(viewFollowMe, constaintId: "constriantHeightFollowMe")

        if hightConstraint != nil {
            viewFollowMe.removeConstraint(hightConstraint!)

            let heightContraints = NSLayoutConstraint(item: viewFollowMe, attribute:
                .Height, relatedBy:.GreaterThanOrEqual , toItem: nil,
                attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0,
                constant: VIEW_HEIGT_BOTTOM)
            viewFollowMe.addConstraint(heightContraints)
        }
```

Comment: removing and adding constraints is an expensive process. Why don't you update the constraint's constant value instead? Or you can set the height constraint for the views A and B proportional to its parent view which is the scrollview. Again, if you just want to fit the subviews according to device height, then what is the purpose of using a scrollView!? ScrollView comes in action only if its content size is greater than its bounds!

Answer (score 0):

First, if your views have a set size, I would recommend rethinking putting them in a scrollview.

If you have a reason for it, your best option to do it automatically would likely be adding constraints for equating the height of the ViewController's view to A and B views.

The more flexible solution would be to handle it in your ViewController code with references to the height constraints of the views. Something like:

```
if (aViewHeightConstraint.constant + bViewHeightConstraint.constant) < desiredHeight {
    bViewHeightConstraint.constant += (aViewHeightConstraint.constant + bViewHeightConstraint.constant) - desiredHeight
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

that's uncompiled, but it should get you down the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Give bottom constraint of your scrollView with respect to view or BottomLayoutGuide and Give bottom constraint of your UIView B to the bottom of scrollview